# Agda: what does `.(` mean?

Tags: syntax, pattern-matching, agda, unification

I was looking at the code in `agda-stdlib/src/Data/Vec/Base.agda`
and saw `.(` in

```
take : ∀ m {n} → Vec A (m + n) → Vec A m
take m xs          with splitAt m xs
take m .(ys ++ zs) | (ys , zs , refl) = ys
```

I tried removing the `.` in front of it and got the following error:

```
Could not parse the left-hand side
take m (ys ++ zs) | (ys , zs , refl)
Operators used in the grammar:
  ++ (infixr operator, level 5) [_++_ (/Users/fss/Dropbox/Documents/projects/Coding/dev/agda/agda-stdlib/src/Data/Vec/Base.agda:99,1-5)]            
  ,  (infixr operator, level 4) [_,_ (/usr/local/Cellar/agda/2.6.1/share/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.10.1/Agda-2.6.1/lib/prim/Agda/Builtin/Sigma.agda:9,15-18)]
when scope checking the left-hand side
take m (ys ++ zs) | (ys , zs , refl) in the definition of take
```

So I'm guessing it is necessary. But I don't understand what it is for exactly. I tried to look in https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1.1 but couldn't find anything about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, in

```
take m (ys ++ zs)
```

the pattern `ys ++ zs` is not valid because it is not a constructor applied on other patterns. If you think about it, in general it doesn't make sense to pattern match as function application because you'd need to be able to invert every function.

However, in

```
take : ∀ m {n} → Vec A (m + n) → Vec A m
take m xs          with splitAt m xs
take m .(ys ++ zs) | (ys , zs , refl) = ys
```

we pattern match on the result of `splitAt` as well. The type of the third argument is `(ys ++ zs) == xs`, and the type of the constructor `refl` is `(ys ++ zs) == (ys ++ zs)`. By unification, that means `xs ~ (ys ++ zs)`, so the second argument to `take` cannot be anything other than `ys ++ zs` in this clause.

And this is exactly what a [dot-pattern](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1/language/function-definitions.html#dot-patterns) means:

> A dot pattern (also called *inaccessible pattern*) can be used when the only type-correct value of the argument is determined by the patterns given for the other arguments. The syntax for a dot pattern is `.t`.